# Typescript generic how to make typeof object-to-array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have this Function

```
export const ObjectToArray = <T>(object: T): { key: any; value: any }[] =>
  Object.entries(object).map(o => ({ key: o[0], value: o[1] }));
```

I want to remove `any` part of result

I even don't know how to start apporach it.
Any hint please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following approach:

```
type Entries<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: { key: P; value: T[P] };
}[keyof T];

export const objectToArray = <T>(obj: T): Entries<T>[] =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(o => ({ key: o[0] as keyof T, value: o[1] }));
```

The `Entries` generic type simply iterates through the keys of `T`, mapping each key into the record you need, to then indexing those keys to create a union of the records.
Inside the `objectToArray` function a type assertion is needed because `Object.entries` does not preserve the informations about the keys of the input object to avoid some unsound situations.